# get onActivityResult for Non Activity Class (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I'm sure there are tons of similar question about this on SO but non just quite yet answers my use case.

I have a BluetoothReader class that doesn't extend any super classes. This calls checks if bluetooth is enabled on a device and prompts a dialog if otherwise.

```
public class BluetoothReader {

   private Activity activity;

   public BluetoothReader(Activity activity){
     bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
     this.activity = activity;
   }
}
```

I turn on the bluetooth using the piece of code below

```
intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH);
```

All works but now my dilemma is that how do i get the result of this check in this same class.

If i were extending the Activity super class, i'ld have just had to override onActivityResult.

I tried:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  // Doesn't work
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think that you should use the "implements" Java keyword

Comment: Where exactly are you calling the startActivityForResult?? In BluetoothReader class?

Comment: onActivityResult will be implemented in activity which is used for calling this startActivityForResult.

Comment: yes @MohammedAtif i want to get the results there too

Comment: As most of the answers suggest, you are supposed to override onActivityRersult in the Activity where you are creating the object for BluettothReader and in the callback, `bluetoothReaderObject.OnActivityResult();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need the result outside of an Activity or Fragment, your Activity class will need to override onActivityResult, then pass that result to your other class by method call.

Answer (score 1):

In your `BluetoothReader` class :

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent result) {
    //some code
}
```

In your main, redirect to this function :

```
@Override 
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent result) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, result);
    BluetoothReader.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, result);
 }
```

Comment: This will not work. Your proposed `BluetoothReader` `onActivityResult()` method is an instance method; you are calling it as if it is a static method.

Comment: @CommonsWare you are correct, do you think it should be `BluetoothReaderInstance` `OnActivityResult()` ?

Comment: That would be odd capitalization for what should be a field on the `Activity`. The only good way that the activity could call a method on a `BluetoothReader` instance is if the `Activity` has a field (e.g., `btReader`) that references that instance.

Answer (score 0):

Activity Result API, works with LifeCycle.
It's a good idea really.